# Image Doesn't Resize for HTML5 Responsive Website

Tags: css, html, image, responsive-design

I'm trying to combine image with text for the header, but the image doesn't resize with it. Although the image appears too big and doesn't adjust in size as I resize the browser window.

HTML Code:

Company Name

## Company Name

CSS:

```css
.image {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
}
.image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Header */
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
#header h1 {
    color: #252122;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    letter-spacing: -0.035em;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

I tried the following code:

```
<h1 id="logo">
    <a>Company Name</a>
</h1>
```

and added the following to the CSS file:

```css
#logo a {
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   width:[image width];
   height:[image height];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The css your using to resize the img:

```
.image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Isn't actually targeting anything as you don't use the class image in your html.

Just add a global style to all your image to make them responsive.

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

height: auto; will keep the images in proportion and max-width: 100%; will keep the image within its parents width but wont stretch it large then its original width.

Comment: I've attempted the following: `<!-- Logo -->
       <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo.png"> Company Name</a></h1>
`    with the suggested global style, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Where are you putting this css? Your html in your question doesn't even link to a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow won't let me comment, so I had to post an answer. You have to add the CSS classes to your HTML tags. I created a Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MQm2oDIS4HiLDSddtbL1?p=preview) with a demo. I'm not sure what else you need it to do.

I used your code and just added a class:

```
<body class="homepage">
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <!-- Logo -->
             <h1 class="image img"><a href="index.html"><a><img src="http://s24.postimg.org/93e2pe9f9/Data_Center_Watermark.png" alt="Company Logo"> Company Name</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining the h1 tag with the image as below code

```
<h1><a href="index.html"><a><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="Company Logo"> Company Name</a></h1>
```

so it is better you give the class name to h1 as

```
<h1 class="h1-image><a href="index.html"><a><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="Company Logo"> Company Name</a></h1>
```

so to make the image resize you just need to call the class and target the img inside that tag as

```
.h1-image img {
    height: 10 rem;
    width: 10 rem;
}
```

Here you need to manually define the height and width by looking at the result. So the better practise for responsive is to use rem or %. And for fully responsive use `@media only screen and (min-width: screen-size)`